# Searching for a value inside an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, exchange-server

I needed to get some help with an array.  I created one array of users with the field name of EmailAddresses and they are formatted as follows:

```
{sip:jsmith@domain.com, SMTP:jsmith@domain.com,  etc....
```

So, in this first array I have about 150 or so users and each entry will have 3 or 4 various proxy addresses.

I want to script adding an additional email address, but before I do the work, I want to check to see if the special email address I designate does not already exist in the first array I just built.  So, my query that is nested in a for each loop is below.

```
If ($NewEmailAddress -contains "*$Users.EmailAddresses*")
    {Write-Host "The user name matches an existing entry." $NewEmailAddress}    
        else {echo "You are clear to use this name" $NewEmailAddress}
```

No matter how I try the search of `-like`, `-contains`, etc... It never seems to find any of the conflicts.  All the result set always says that I am clear to use the existing address even though I know there is a conflict.

Is my problem the search within the array or is there a better way to build the array in the first place to include the primary smtp address and all the aliases?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a little bit easier than you're trying to make it.

Let's say that you have an array of e-mail addresses, as follows:

```
$EmailList = @('trevor@contoso.com', 'nancy@contoso.com', 'billy@contoso.com');
```

If you're trying to check to see if the array contains a particular item, all you have to do is put the array on the left side of the `-contains` operator, and on the right-hand side, the value that you're checking for.

```
$EmailList -contains 'trevor@contoso.com';
```

That should yield a result of: `$true`.

If you have an array that you need to check against an array, you'll have to iterate over each element. Using the `$EmailList` array that we had earlier, and a new array called `$User.EmailAddresses`, we could do something like this:

```
foreach ($EmailAddress in $User.EmailAddresses) {
    if ($EmailList -contains $EmailAddress) {
        # Do something
    }
    else {
        # Do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if ( ($Users.EmailAddresses | ? {$_ -like "*$NewEmailAddress*"}).Length -gt 0 ) {
  Write-Host "Address $NewEmailAddress is already assigned."
} else {
  Write-Host "Address $NewEmailAddress is not yet assigned."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time using this site and I wanted to say thanks for all the answers.  It definitely helped push me in the right direction.

What really happened was my logic in my "IF" statement.

```
 If ($NewEmailAddress -contains "*$Users.EmailAddresses*")
```

It was opposite of what I needed.  My logic was asking if the Array was contained in the users email address and the reality is that I needed to flip that and ask if the email address was contained in the array.  I realized that when I saw Trevor's comment.  His logic was opposite (and correct) from mine.  :)

Thanks again for all the help.

Michael